# How to call a method of a method of a mocked class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

How to call a method of a method of a mocked class?

```java
when(mockedClass.method1().method2()).thenReturn(x);
```

This line of code is throwing

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException`

I am not able to call the 2nd method after mocking the class.
I tried `doReturn`, spy but didn't work.

Any solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`method2()` does not belong to the type you mocked. It belongs to the type that is returned by `method1()`. You can only tell the mock what to return on calls to `method1()` (that's the reason for the `misusing` part in the exceptions package name).

In theory, you the create a mock for the type returned by `method1()` and instruct `mockedClass` to return that second mock and then tell the new mock to return `x` when `method2()` is called. But letting mocks return other mocks is usually a really bad idea for a multitude of reasons.

Without knowing your actual code and what you really want to achieve, it is really hard to give any advice on this. Therefore I can only offer some general hints, which might or might not apply to you situation.

Usually, `object1.method1().method2()` call chain should be avoided. The "Tell, don't ask" principle says, that asking an object for *something* and then operating on that *something* should be avoided (**Tell** an object what to do, **instead of asking** it for things and do it yourself). The call chain implies that `method1()` is returning another object (`object2`) which is then used to call `method2()`. Instead of this, you should add a method to `object1` which is doing the call to `method2()` and returns its result. Simple example:

This is what you classes might look like

```java
public class C1 {
    private C2 o2;

    public C2 method1() {
        return o2;
    }
}

public class C2 {
    public int method2() {
        return computeValue();
    }
}

// somewhere else:
int value = object1.method1().method2();
```

Instead, you could design it like this:

```java
public class C1 {
    private C2 o2;

    //public C2 method1() {
    //    return o2;
    //}
    public int method3() {
        return o2.method2();
    }
}

public class C2 {
    public int method2() {
        return computeValue();
    }
}

// somewhere else:
//int value = object1.method1().method2();
int value = object1.method3();
```

This way you avoid the call chain and `C1` does not have to reveal that it contains a value of type `C2` which means you could change that without the callers being aware of it.

Apart from the better design and the avoidance of the call chain (also called a "train wreck"), this allows you to do the following for your mocking situation:

```java
//when(mockedClass.method1().method2()).thenReturn(x);
when(mockedClass.method3()).thenReturn(x);
```

Comment: You can refer for the code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999768/junit-5-test-failure-due-to-org-mockito-exceptions-misusing-missingmethodinvocat